# How to simplify this Rust code with nested `match` with guards returning `Result`s?

Tags: rust, refactoring, simplify

Is there a simpler way of writing this Rust code? For full context, see [this PR](https://github.com/srid/nixci/pull/1).

```rust
impl FromArgValue for FlakeRef {
    fn from_arg_value(s: &str) -> std::result::Result<FlakeRef, String> {
        match Url::parse(s) {
            Ok(url)
                if url.scheme() == "https" && url.host() == Some(Host::Domain("github.com")) =>
            {
                match url.path_segments().map(|c| c.collect::<Vec<_>>()) {
                    None => Ok(FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string())),
                    Some(paths) => match paths[..] {
                        [user, repo, "pull", pr_] => match pr_.parse() {
                            Ok(pr) => Ok(FlakeRef::GithubPR {
                                owner: user.to_string(),
                                repo: repo.to_string(),
                                pr: pr,
                            }),
                            Err(_) => Ok(FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string())),
                        },
                        _ => Ok(FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string())),
                    },
                }
            }
            _ => Ok(FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string())),
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit (July 12)**: Based on the answers below I've simplified this further to the following. Anything else that can be done to simplify it further?

```rust
    use try_guard::guard;

    /// Parse a Github PR URL into its owner, repo, and PR number
    pub fn parse_url(url: &String) -> Option<(String, String, u64)> {
        let url = Url::parse(url).ok()?;
        guard!(url.scheme() == "https" && url.host() == Some(Host::Domain("github.com")));
        let paths = url.path_segments().map(|c| c.collect::<Vec<_>>())?;
        match paths[..] {
            [user, repo, "pull", pr_] => {
                let pr = pr_.parse::<u64>().ok()?;
                Some((user.to_string(), repo.to_string(), pr))
            }
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn from_arg_value(s: &str) -> std::result::Result<FlakeRef, String> {
        match github::PullRequest::parse_url(&s.to_string()) {
            Some((owner, repo, pr)) => Ok(FlakeRef::GithubPR {
                owner: owner,
                repo: repo,
                pr: pr,
            }),
            None => Ok(FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string())),
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `let else` to avoid the pyramid of doom.

Comment: I would definitely advocate for using `.map_err` and `?` to propagate errors instead of `match`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert this into a function that returns `Option` and use `None` as the error path. This will let you use the try operator `?` to return early. Then you can convert both paths into `Ok`.

```rs
fn from_arg_value(s: &str) -> Result<FlakeRef, String> {
    fn from_arg_value_internal(s: &str) -> Option<FlakeRef> {
        let url = Url::parse(s).ok()?;
        if url.scheme() == "https" && url.host() == Some(Host::Domain("github.com")) {
            return None;
        }

        let path_segments = url.path_segments()?;
        let paths: Vec<_> = path_segments.collect();

        let [user, repo, "pull", pr_] = paths[..] else {
            return None;
        };

        let pr = pr_.parse().ok()?;

        Some(FlakeRef::GithubPR {
            owner: user.to_string(),
            repo: repo.to_string(),
            pr,
        })
    }

    let flake = from_arg_value_internal(s).unwrap_or_else(|| FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string()));
    Ok(flake)
}
```

In general, the only time you should need to match an `Option` or `Result` is when you are doing complex logic in both branches. Otherwise, there'll be a method that works in less code. You can find these by reading through the documentation for [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) or [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), which are very similar.

A separate thing is that you can avoid creating a `Vec` by calling `next` repeatedly.

```rs
let mut path_segments = url.path_segments()?;
let user = path_segments.next()?;
let method = path_segments.next()?;
let pr_ = path_segments.next()?;

if method != "pull" || path_segments.next().is_some() {
    return None;
}
```

Comment: Those `let..return None` patterns can further be simplified using https://crates.io/crates/try-guard

Answer (score 0):

This approach sticks closer to the original program and works according to exclusion procedure with [BallpointBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496433/ballpointben)'s suggestion:

```
fn from_arg_value(s: &str) -> std::result::Result<FlakeRef, String> {
    'end: {
        let Ok(url) = Url::parse(s) else { break 'end; };
        if url.scheme() != "https" || url.host() != Some(Host::Domain("github.com")) { break 'end; }
        let Some(paths) = url.path_segments().map(|c| c.collect::<Vec<_>>()) else { break 'end; };
        let [user, repo, "pull", pr_] = paths[..] else { break 'end; };
        let Ok(pr) = pr_.parse() else { break 'end; };
        return Ok(FlakeRef::GithubPR {
            owner: user.to_string(),
            repo: repo.to_string(),
            pr,
        });
    }
    Ok(FlakeRef::Flake(s.to_string()))
}
```